# Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' with Redis

Tags: java, spring, maven, redis

i'm trying to run   Maven Spring application using Redis+ MYSQL, but i unable to run the app due to this error, i've been searching all over the web for proper answer but misfind.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-08 11:41:31.068 ERROR 8448 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.bookstore.BookstoreAngularApplication.main(BookstoreAngularApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:50) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:48) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:330) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.setConfig(LettuceConnection.java:738) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:68) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:251) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:100) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:90) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:225) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:199) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) ~[netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) ~[netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_25]Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-08 11:41:31.068 ERROR 8448 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.bookstore.BookstoreAngularApplication.main(BookstoreAngularApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:50) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:48) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:330) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.setConfig(LettuceConnection.java:738) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:68) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:251) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:100) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:90) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:225) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:199) ~[lettuce-4.3.1.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:351) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450) ~[netty-transport-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) ~[netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) ~[netty-common-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

that was the error i received when i'm trying to run the springboot app.

my LettuceConnection bean is:

```
 @EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

my http session strategy bean:

```
@Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy(){

        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy() ;
    }
```

my related dependencies in pom.xml are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

amy help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start by inspecting the root cause in the stack trace:

> `Caused by: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events`

It says that configuration of `notify-keyspace-events` in your Redis instance is not supported. Vanilla Redis does support configuration of `notify-keyspace-events` so that's a hint that you run on a non-vanilla Redis (such as Amazon's Redis variant ElastiCache, Microsoft's Azure or you have something in front of your Redis instance that prevents configuration).

Keyspace events are required for session expiry hence Spring Session attempts to auto-configure your Redis server. You need to configure `notify-keyspace-events` to `Egx` (or `A` for all) to make Spring Session work.

You can also provide a bean of the type `ConfigureRedisAction` to configure Redis programmatically.

References:

- Redis Auto-Configuration via [`ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java#L55).
- [`ConfigureRedisAction`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/ConfigureRedisAction.java) API.

Answer (score 4):

Adding following configuration will help you

```
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction;

@Bean
public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
     return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
}
```

Comment: This worked. AWS Redis MemoryDB has the same issue as ElastiCache, the "notify-keyspace-events" parameter needs to be enabled: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/parametergroups.redis.html

Answer (score 2):

Before going into any further details of the issue,please make sure that you have redis server available in your local and it's up and running.
To get the redis server up and running do the followings :

1. Download the zip file from 
   https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases/tag/win-2.8.2104
2. Extract the zip file and run redis-server.exe **with cmd** .
   In the command you should specify the maximum heap memory,
   for example **D:\Redis\redis-server.exe --maxheap 1024M**

Answer (score 1):

AWS ElastiCache comes with keyspace notifications **disabled by default**, but you can enable it via parameter group.

Quoting the official documentation on [How do I implement Redis keyspace notifications in ElastiCache?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-redis-keyspace-notifications/)

> 1. Open the ElastiCache console.
> 2. To see a list of all available parameter groups, choose Parameter Groups in the navigation pane.
> 3. Select the parameter group that you want to modify. Note: You can't modify a default parameter group. If the parameter groups listed are
>    all default, create a new parameter group by choosing Create Parameter
>    Group, select a Family, and then choose Create.
> 4. Choose Edit Parameters.
> 5. Scroll to notify-keyspace-events, and then enter AKE in the Value field. For more information on allowed values, see Redis 2.8.6 added
>    parameters.
> 6. Choose Save Changes. The changes take effect immediately without restarting the cluster. Note: Be sure to assign the new modified
>    parameter group to your Redis cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Spring tries to execute a Redis configuration action that enables keyspace notifications. It does this so it gets notified of session expirations. A properly secured Redis instance doesn't allow this, thus this action must be disabled.

Add `configure-action: NONE` configuration property to your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  session:
    redis:
      configure-action: NONE
```

If you use Redis on Amazon AWS as ElastiCache or MemoryDB, you can enable keyspace notifications by setting the `notify-keyspace-events` parameter to `Egx` : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/parametergroups.redis.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself and after doing a little research I personally believe the issue is because there is not an instance of Redis running locally. I suggest installing and running a local instance.

If this is on windows I suggest downloading an installer from:
https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases